# Differentiating REST status codes

Tags: rest, http

Lately, I have started adding status codes to my responses instead of returning them directly.

Let's assume `/person/1` returns a person with id 1 from the DB. If the person does not exist, should I return 404 status? How am I supposed to differentiate if the endpoint does not exist on the server or the resource does not exist?

Now, let's assume I have a POST endpoint for inserting users. What if that endpoint checks if the email is formed correctly and I return 400? How should I know if the request was not formed correctly and did not route to any servlets or if it indeed reached the servlet which decided that email is badly formed?

Is it a good practice to always return a 200 OK response from all of my servlets indicating that the application has done its job regardless of the outcome and write the status in a json field `status` or is this an overkill and an anti-pattern?

I do not have a lot of experience nor knowledge of HTTP servers so I am not sure I am explaining this (nor using it) right, so I apologize for the broad descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's assume /person/1 returns a person with id 1 from the DB. If the person does not exist, should I return 404 status? How am I supposed to differentiate if the endpoint does not exist on the server or the resource does not exist?

To a client it doesn't matter whether the resource or the endpoint did not exist. All it is told by the server is that for the given URI there is no representation available.

As inf3rno already mentioned a client is usually served all of the URIs a client will need by the server directly in a response. Through bookmarking or including links in some external resource certain links might get invalid over time and as such a `404 Not Found` response just informs the client that no representation is available for the given URI.

A client typically is also not interested in the internals of an API but just to send or receive data it can work upon.

A further misconception many users have, unfortunately, is, that they already assume certain resources to return certain [types](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). Such types may lead to failures on the client side if the expected representation format ever changes. In addition to that the URI structure itself, including any path, matrix and query parameters, should not be used to deduce any logical structure of the API, its exposed endpoints or the logical structure of the resources to other resources of that API. A URI as a whole is a pointer to a resource. A resource may have a dozens of links pointing to it. You might think of a URI as cache-key for representations returned that, on consecutive invocations are further served by the cache instead of the actual server. This is actually one of the constraints REST imposes and is widely used on the Web.

> Now, let's assume I have a POST endpoint for inserting users. What if that endpoint checks if the email is formed correctly and I return 400? How should I know if the request was not formed correctly and did not route to any servlets or if it indeed reached the servlet which decided that email is badly formed?

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) defines `POST` as an all-purpose tool that should be used if other methods aren't fitting for the task at hand. It explicitely states that the payload provided by that method will be `processed according to the resource's own specific semantics`. So, if you need to validate an email-address of a user before persisting it or before starting a calculation, background process or whatever, fine, do that :) Even [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), which is often said to only replace the current representatin with the given one in the request, is not only allowed but also encouraged to perform verifications regarding any constraints the server has for the target resource and therefore it should refuse payloads that do not fit its expectations.

The quintesence here is, that a server should provide a client always with as much information as possible to let a client determine what to do next. Think of a Web based application which you access through your browser. If you receive a `400 Bad Request` the browser will usually tell what the server didn't like about your request, i.e. incomplete syntax or missing value of a required field. The same holds true for REST APIs as they are basically just a generalization of the interaction model used on the Web. So the same concepts that apply to the Web also apply to REST :)

By that, each HTTP status code has its own semantics and should help the client to determine what the client should do next. A [`400 Bad Request`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) i.e. states that the server either cannot or will not process the request due to something that the server considers to be a client based error and it's up to the client to correct that failure and resend the request.

A [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) on the other hand indicates that the client used a HTTP method not supported by the targeted endpoint. An error response not only indicates that to the client but also which methods are allowed on the targeted endpoint within an `Alllow` response header.

Each of the HTTP status codes specified in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) has their own semantics and its probably advisable to at least skim over these. You can also lookup all available status codes at [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) that provides links to the specificaton describing those status codes.

> Is it a good practice to always return a 200 OK response from all of my servlets indicating that the application has done its job regardless of the outcome and write the status in a json field status or is this an overkill and an anti-pattern?

As with error codes also the success codes (in the 200 range) have their own semantics. If a new resource is created as outcome of processing a request (via `PUT` or `POST`) a client should be notified with a `201 Created` status response that furthremore contains a HTTP `Location` header containing a URI targeting at the newly created resource.

If a server may take some time in order to calculate a response it is probably advisable to return a [`202 Accepted`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3) response in order to inform a client about the pending request. A client can later on poll for the request either after some threshold period or after getting notified by the server through callback mechanisms such as email-notification or similar stuff. Due to German law restrictions i.e. German companies have to maintain archives of their messages exchanged via EDI. We, as an EDI provider, offer our clients to perform an archive of their exchanged messages via triggering one of our HTTP endpoints. Depending on the number of messages exchange by that company and the time period selected the archive should be generated for, this process may take some time (a couple of hours to be more concrete) and instead of letting the client wait for that period we simply return `202 Accepted` and start the archiving process in the back. Depending on the configuration they either poll for the finished archive, get an information about the final result or directly get the archive sent through email if the file isn't to large.

[`204 No Content`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) is also quite useful if a client performs an update onto a resource. As `PUT` is generally defined as replace the current representation with the one provided in the payload, upon receiving a `204 No Content` response the client knows that the server applied the update and the current representation does look like the requested one by the client. Thus the server does not need to inform the client further how the current representation looks like, as the client already knows how it should look like. However, in case the server had to convert the payload to a different representation that maybe lead to an other outcome, it is probably benefitial to inform a client about the new state of the resource within a `200 OK` response including the a representation of the outcome of the update process.

Returning `200 OK` for a failure including a JSON payload with fields indicating about the error is for sure a bad way to proceed. Not only does it give clients a wrong hint but the response might also be cached by intermediaries and returned to other clients requesting the same even when the failure might only be of temporary nature (DB crash or the like). In additon to that is such a JSON payload proabably using a non-standardized format and thus requires out-of-band knowledge to actually process the message. While we humans are quite capable of figuring out what's going on, computers aren't yet that smart on their own.

I hope you can see that HTTP offers a lot of semantics on when to use what method or response code. They are there for a reason and therefore also should be used if the circumstances are right.

Comment: WOW, that was a thorough explanation :D I have already written quite a few REST applications, but my colleagues would occasionally ask me something like: is 404 was caused because they sent the wrong id or targeted the wrong endpoint (even though we use Swagger :P). Your answer sure does cast more light on the problem. I actually thought that returning 200 was a bad idea, but that was something we discussed and since we are starting a new project now, I wanted to change this. Thanks for all the arguments I can throw at them now, especially the one about cache :D

Answer (score 1):

In GET request, `404` status is just a response code. You have to provide error message in body of the response in case when record is not found for the id provided.

For POST request, you can return `400` error code with specifying in the body which fields are missing/failing validation.

For url not found, User will always get the `404` error code.

For succcessful GET or POST request, you can return the response with `200` status

Answer (score 1):

> How am I supposed to differentiate if the endpoint does not exist on
>   the server or the resource does not exist?

The endpoint is the IRI (URI) of the web resource in this case. If the endpoint does not exist, then there is a good chance that the web resource does not exist either. It is an unlikely scenario, since you got your URIs from the server (HATEOAS), but it can happen if something changes between two requests, e.g. the URI template changes or somebody deletes the resource. In all of these cases the 404 is a fine HTTP status code. You can elaborate in the error message or use an additional error code, but for me it does not make sense, because the URI template change is a rare event. It would make the client more flexible though, since it could clear the cache and retry with a new link.